# Why indexOf print -1 although the values are in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I don't understand why indexOf() print -1 although the values are in the array. 
I have the same result with the function includes() it returns me false.

I think I don't understand something or I forgot something.

Do you have any idea that why the result are negative when the we can see that the values are in the array ?

Thank you

```
var i = 0
let array = []

class MovieRow extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.addFavorite = this.addFavorite.bind(this)
        this.deleteFavorite = this.deleteFavorite.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            isFaved: false,
            favMovie: ""
        }
    }

    addFavorite() {
        this.setState({isFaved: true})
        this.state.favMovie = "".concat(baseURL, 'movie/', this.props.movie.id ,'?api_key=', APIKEY)    
        var counts = []
        for (var i = 0; i < myFavoriteMovies.length; i++) {
            var index = myFavoriteMovies[i]
            counts[index] = counts[index] ? counts[index] + 1 : 1;
        }       
        if(myFavoriteMovies.indexOf(this.state.favMovie) === -1) {
            myFavoriteMovies.push(this.state.favMovie)  
            localStorage.setItem(this.props.movie.id, this.state.favMovie)  
        }
    }

    deleteFavorite() {
        this.setState({isFaved: false})
        var removeThisMovie = myFavoriteMovies.indexOf(this.state.favMovie)
        myFavoriteMovies.splice(removeThisMovie,1)
        localStorage.removeItem(this.props.movie.id,removeThisMovie)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(array)
        console.log("Value = "+this.props.movie.id)
        console.log("Res indexOf = " +array.indexOf(this.props.movie.id))
    }
```

[image: display problem]

Comment: You are comparing strings and integers.

Comment: can you place the code of inherited class

Comment: Oups... Thank you David

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`indexOf` and `includes` search for exact matches.

`this.props.movie.id` will be `491418` while the value in the array is `"491418"`.

You need to convert `this.props.movie.id` to a string.

```
array.indexOf("" + this.props.movie.id)
```